# Taking first and last characters from string variable and inserting xxx in between them in android

Tags: android, string, variables, substring

I have a value in a string variable. I need to take first and last letters from the string variable. Append it with xxx in between them. For example, if the string variable value is "googleuser", then i should get the output as "gxxxr". How is this made? I tried many ways, suggested by google, but still didn't find anything which is helpful to me. Can some one suggest me a way for this. I tried the charat(index) function but it returned wrong results.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have done so far? charAt method should work for what you are doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that using the `StringBuilder`:

```
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append(text.charAt(0));
    s.append("xxx");
    s.append(text.charAt(text.length -1));
    s.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regexp

```
String s = "aaa";
s.repalceAll("(.){1}(.)+(.){1}", "$1xxx$3");
```